# Is this a SQL Server Management Studio bug?

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-view, ssms-2012

I create a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise view thusly -

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTest]
AS
WITH cte_LCH AS
(
    select *, Rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimId ORDER BY Id DESC)
    from ClaimHistories
    where Status in (1,2)
)
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Claims.Id AS ClaimId, cte_LCH.Id AS ClaimHistoryId, 
           dbo.Claims.PlanId, dbo.Providers.ChainId, dbo.Claims.MemberId
     FROM  dbo.TxDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           cte_LCH ON dbo.TxDetails.Id = cte_LCH.TxDetailId LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.ClaimHistoryPrices ON cte_LCH.Id = dbo.ClaimHistoryPrices.ClaimHistoryId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.Claims INNER JOIN
           dbo.Providers ON dbo.Claims.ProviderId = dbo.Providers.Id INNER JOIN
           dbo.Members ON dbo.Claims.MemberId = dbo.Members.Id ON cte_LCH.ClaimId = dbo.Claims.Id
     WHERE cte_LCH.Rank = 1
     ORDER BY ClaimId
```

but when I ask SSMS to "Design" the saved view, it only shows this -

```
SELECT *, Rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimId
ORDER BY Id DESC)
FROM      ClaimHistories
WHERE     Status IN (1, 2))
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Claims.Id AS ClaimId, cte_LCH.Id AS ClaimHistoryId, dbo.Claims.PlanId, dbo.Providers.ChainId, dbo.Claims.MemberId
     FROM dbo.TxDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          cte_LCH ON dbo.TxDetails.Id = cte_LCH.TxDetailId LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.ClaimHistoryPrices ON cte_LCH.Id = dbo.ClaimHistoryPrices.ClaimHistoryId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.Claims INNER JOIN
          dbo.Providers ON dbo.Claims.ProviderId = dbo.Providers.Id INNER JOIN
          dbo.Members ON dbo.Claims.MemberId = dbo.Members.Id ON cte_LCH.ClaimId = dbo.Claims.Id
     WHERE cte_LCH.Rank = 1
     ORDER BY ClaimId
```

and does not show the "WITH" clause so in fact I cannot actually edit and save the view getting an incorrect syntax complaint since an extra ')' char, and if I copy, it is not executable code. If I script the view to a query window however, I get the original code as I created it. The view with the CTE seems to work fine however.

My question is - is this normal? Can a CTE be used in a view like this? Should I see the WITH clause if I ask SSMS to design the saved view?

Thx, Dave

Comment: What is your question? this sounds more like a bug report than a question. If you want to report a bug to Microsoft report it on the [connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).

Comment: Obviously my question was - is this normal or a bug?

Comment: Top 100 percent in a view is pointless. The output of your view is not guaranteed to be in that order. If you want data in a particular order it MUST be ordered in the query that retrieves it. Consider what the order would be if you had two views and they had conflicting order by clauses. Which one would "win". If you want ordered there is one and only one way to ensure the order, an order by clause.

Comment: A better option than using the awful visual designer is to use t-sql. :)

Comment: Stop "designing" views. The designer is terrible. Right-click, script view as, alter to, new query editor window.

Comment: @Sean - Thx. I know about the top 100 and order by but that is what I got out of the designer. Not my question though.

Comment: The view designer was created in what, SQL Server 2000? Common Table Expressions are as of 2005. It, like much of the visual designers should be avoided as they are unloved, unkept pieces of garbage.

Comment: Sure, I'd love an updated designer w/ cross database, CTEs etc, but SQL is not my main thing so use SSMS Designer for quick and dirty. Still, is this a bug in the designer be it as it is or am I doing something wrong with CTEs?

Comment: You can find an answer to that fairly easily by trying to run the [original] CREATE VIEW statement in a query window.

Comment: @Andriy - as I mentioned, if I script the view, I get the original just fine, it is just "Design" that seems to be not showing the CTE clause properly.

Comment: I'll chalk this up to a bug in SSMS designer. Can anyone recommend a decent 3rd party designer if we are not supposed to use the included designer?

Answer (score 1):

TOP 100 PERCENT ORDER BY in View worked in SQL Server 2012, and does not work in SQL Server 2014 - I would classify that as a BUG, regardless of other people design choices :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

> A CTE can also be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the
>   defining SELECT statement of the view.

So it sounds to me like you have found a bug in the SQL Server Management Studio designer.  [Another post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3aaa6ed7-c2c1-46de-93c6-cb1756130838/editing-a-view-in-management-studio-with-cte) says the same issue happened in SQL Server 2008 R2.

(Another reference on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) says the same thing about creating views with CTEs.)